# My part is not fading(lerping) between colors

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a part constantly fading between two colors but for some reason I am getting this error. How do I fix it?[image]

```
while true do
    script.Parent.Color = script.Parent.Color:Lerp(Color3.fromRGB(52, 63, 127))
    repeat 
        wait()
    until script.Parent.Color == Color3.fromRGB(52, 63, 127)
    script.Parent.Color = script.Parent.Color:Lerp(Color3.fromRGB(127, 0, 127))
    repeat 
        wait()
    until script.Parent.Color == Color3.fromRGB(127, 0, 127)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You gave to add a second parametre `alpha` (a number between 0 and 1) to all calls of `Color:Lerp`, setting the proportion in which colors are mixed, after the `Color3.fromRGB` calls.

See https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/Color3.

Why is the third parametre called second? Because technically, first is `self` (since the function `Lerp` is called after `:`), the second is the colour and the third is `alpha`.